# Using PowerShell to rename files having an even number in their base name

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have files like this in the current directory:

[image]

Now I want to add `2` to the file base name when it is an even number. What I mean is that I would like to have:

```
000252.png → 000254.png
000254.png → 000256.png
000256.png → 000258.png
```

In other words, this is the end result I would like to have:
[image]

How do I use `PowerShell` to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer

Assuming the working directory contains all the files to rename (and only those files), here is a one liner to rename them:

```
dir . | sort -des | % { if ($_.BaseName % 2 -eq 0 ) { mv $_ $((2 + $_.BaseName).ToString("000000") + $_.Extension) } }
```

#### Explanation

- `dir .` lists the files in the current directory (`.`). `dir` is an alias for [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem).
- `sort -des` sorts these files in descending order (`-des`) of their name. `sort` is an alias for [Sort-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) and `-des` is short for `-Descending`.
- `%` is an alias for [ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) which executes a script (enclosed in curly braces (`{}`) for each item in the pipeline.
- `if ($_.BaseName % 2 -eq 0 )` is used to check whether the base name contains an even number using the [equality](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) (`-eq`) and [modulus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators) (`%`) operators.
- `mv` is an alias for [Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Move-Item), which can be used to rename a file.
- `$_` is the [current item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) in the pipeline.
- `(2 + $_.BaseName)` extracts the base name and adds 2.
- `.ToString("000000")` [formats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring) this new number [with leading zeros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) (assuming you need a total of six digits).
- `+ $_.Extension` adds the original file [extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension) (`$_.Extension` is the extension of the current file in the pipeline and that includes the `.`)

#### Remark

This solution would rename a file named `000998.png` to `001000.png` (in other words, it makes sure that there are 6 digits in total).

Comment: Oh, note the `000251.png` is keep same..

Comment: Oh you're right! I didn't see the that only files with an even base name must be renamed. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @YoussefAbidi Nice use of `ToString`!

Answer (score 2):

```
$files = "C:\files"

# for each file in the directory
# sort descending. this avoids trying to rename 252 -> 254 since 254 may exist.
gci $files | sort -des | % {
    $b = $_.BaseName                    # full basename, eg 000252
    $int = $b / 1                       # cast as an int, eg 252

    # if the integer is even
    if($int % 2 -eq 0) {

        # increase the name by 2
        $newBaseName = $b -replace $int,''
        $int = $int + 2

        # prepare the new basename
        $newBaseName = $newBaseName + [string]$int + $_.Extension

        # rename the files
        rename-item $files\$_ $files\$newBaseName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Remove `-WhatIf` after you verify that this works correctly.

You didn't specify this as a requirement, so I didn't account for it, but know that a file of name "000998.png" would be renamed as "0001000.png", not "001000.png".